# Mathematical relations between functions

Tags: function, math, functional-programming, function-composition, mathematical-expressions

I'm going to use an exemple to ask my question, lets suppose we have a function G composed of 3 functions f1, f2 and f3, like this picture :  [image: g1]
the function `G = f3(f2(f1(input))) or g = f3 º f2 º f1`
an other example when G is composed of 4 functions like so : [image: g2] where f1 and f2 are not necessarily parallel, how can we write G?

Comment: in second example f2 does not have input, can it be simplified to constant argument to f3?

Comment: I forgot to draw it , it does have an input, i have edited the question

Comment: in the first image the arrow from f1 to f2 is easy, but why are there 2 arrows from f2 to f3? If in the first picture f1 takes as argument **input** and serves itselfe as input for f2 which serves as input for f3, you cold write your function g in image #2 as: `G = f4(f3(f1(input, f2(input))))`

Comment: How do you define "not necessarily parallel" in mathematical terms? Ignoring this constraint I would write: G = f4 º f3 º (f1 x f2)

Comment: @Radinator the 2 arrows means the output is a tuple or in this case a couple

Comment: Okay @PeterG., exactly i'm not sure how, if they where parallel i think it should be like this : G = f4 º f3 º (f1 , f2), not parallel i suppose like you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to have a look at [arrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(computer_science)). With them, your functions could be expressed as follows:

```
G1 = f1 >>> f2 >>> f3
G2 = (f1 *** f2) >>> f3 >>> f4
```

Notice that there is no difference between one and two lines between two function blocks - two arguments is equivalent to one tuple argument. It only will matter if the lines point to different blocks.